# Node js mysql stored procedure call in a for loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures, bulk

So, I'm currently using mysql npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql. I have a requirement where I'll have to call a stored procedure multiple times with the caveat that subsequent stored procedure calls depend on the previous call. Pseudo code will be as follows:

```
let mysql = require("mysql");

let mysqlPoolConnection = mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit: 20,
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      port: '3306',
      user: 'user1',
      password: 'pwd',
      database: 'mysql_db'
});


for (let index = 0; index < params.length; index++) {
    let sp_ProcedureCall = "CALL sp_StoredProcedure(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    let sp_ProcedureParams = [params[index].firstParam, params[index].secondParam, params[index].thirdParam, params[index].fourthParam];
    // This is where the issue is. I'd like to call the stored procedure once and then once I get a response from it then make subsequent calls. Basically, depending on the previous stored procedure result, I decide whether I continue with subsequent calls or not.
    mysqlPoolConnection.query(sp_ProcedureCall, sp_ProcedureParams, (errorObj, responseObj, fieldsObj) => {

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS is asynchronous, meaning your for-loop iterates without waiting for the result of the call. You need to control the flow of your program if you want to "wait" for previous results.

Look at a library like [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) to enabled that type of control flow. From your description, [eachSeries()](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) might be a good fit - to run a function for each value in an array, and only run one at a time. (Or reduce, depending what you need - there are other options too)

Comment: Let me try async and eachSeries and let you all know how it goes. The reason is that the stored procedure has transactions which will take time to run and its a legacy stored procedure hence can't change it much. Which is why I want to execute it one at a time and decide whether I'd want to continue with the next call or not if there's a fatal error.

Comment: I'm going to accept clay's answer because this worked for me on this problem.